# Hapi Fhir query with AND / OR with map

Tags: hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

Using Hapi Fhir, I try to write a query to use a map to pass in where condition, as follow:

```
Map<String, List<IQueryParameterType>> hmParameter = criteria.getMapForWhere();

Bundle bundle = fhirClientR4Configuration.clientFhihrR4().search().forResource(ServiceRequest.class)
            .where(hmParameter).returnBundle(Bundle.class).execute();
```

My criteria object has a method `getMapForWhere()` where I populate this map with information inside my wrapper front end object as follow:

```
public Map<String, List<IQueryParameterType>> getMapForWhere() {
    Map<String, List<IQueryParameterType>> hmOut = new HashMap<String, List<IQueryParameterType>>();
    // Adding STATUS
    if (this.status != null && !this.status.equals("")) {
        StringParam sp = new StringParam();
        sp.setValue(this.status);
        List<IQueryParameterType> lst = new ArrayList<IQueryParameterType>();
        lst.add(sp);
        hmOut.put(ServiceRequest.SP_STATUS, lst);
    }

    // Adding INTENT
    if (this.intent != null && !this.intent.equals("")) {
        StringParam sp = new StringParam();
        sp.setValue(this.intent);
        List<IQueryParameterType> lst = new ArrayList<IQueryParameterType>();
        lst.add(sp);
        hmOut.put(ServiceRequest.SP_INTENT, lst);
    }

    return hmOut;
}
```

This code works fine when I want to wirte a query with all AND.

But if I want to add another condition as follow:

```
    List<IQueryParameterOr> lstOr = new ArrayList<IQueryParameterOr>();
    
    StringOrListParam lstServices = new StringOrListParam();
    
    StringParam sp = new StringParam();
    StringParam sg = new StringParam();
    
    sp.setValue(MEDICAL_SERVICE_PAI);
    sg.setValue(SOCIAL_SERVICE_PAI);
    lstServices.addOr(sp);
    lstServices.addOr(sg);
    lstOr.add(lstServices);
    
    hmOut.put(ServiceRequest.SP_CATEGORY, lstOr);
```

Obviously hmOut goes in error because definition of that map is different. But I don't know how to convert `IParameterOr` with `IParameterType`.